# Why do scrollbars appear in flexbox with overflow: visible?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, flexbox

As seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3y92d1o/1/), I have a div with `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: visible`, and it still displays a scrollbar. Removing the `display: flex` or height attributes from outer div, or `overflow-x: hidden` fixes the problem.

Here's the fiddle HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Text<br>More text<br>Even more text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    display: flex;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
}
div.inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with overflow-x/y is that `visible` can't be mixed with another value, so in this case, `visible` will be treated as `auto`.